# Skip and Take not working with MySQL EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to paginate `Products` from MySQL db, but if I use `Skip()` or `Take()` it returns an empty Json array as my web api response like this

```
[]
```

But extension methods such as `FirstOrDefault()`, `Where()` ... works fine. Here's the code snippet:

```
public IActionResult GetPage(int page, int pageSize = 2)
{            
    int productCount = _context.Products.Count(); // 5
    float totalPages = (float)Math.Ceiling((float)productCount / pageSize); //2.5 -- round to 3

    if (page < 1 || page > totalPages) return NotFound();
    var products = _context.Products.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize); //skip & take err mysql ef

    return Ok(products);
}
```

I even hardcoded the query `.Skip(1).Take(2)` with no luck. Anyone have faced this problem or know a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried order your query before to apply Skip and Take ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in `MySql.Data` EF connector provided by Oracle, bug details is posted [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82991).

**Alternative solution:**

I changed to another connector called [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), now `Skip` and `Take` works perfectly fine. You can search nuget for `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and install appropriate version for your project.

To use, simply change `.UseMySQL` to `.UseMySql` when configuring `DbContext`, as oracle connector use `SQL` and pomelo use `Sql` only casing is different.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I knwon the answer is Old ... but ... in EF mysql you need do pass one order by or order by desc before the skip.

**Real solution, not alternative:**

like this:

```
var yourVar = dbContext.LinkText
                       .Where(x => x.active)
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.startDate)
                       .Skip(50)
                       .Take(10);
```

You can use with any logic on skip and take like this :

```
query
.OrderByDescending(x => x.startDate)
.Skip(page <= 1 ? 0 : (page - 1) * (qty == 0 ? 10 : qty))
.Take(qty == 0 ? 10 : qty);
```

and then the mySQL will recieve the code:

```
*...the query...*     
ORDER BY  `Extent1`.`startDate` DESC 
     LIMIT 0,10
```