# Error: The method or operation is not implemented. while scaffolding MYSQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using .net core 2.0. I have installed the following nuget Packages:
1: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`
2: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
3: `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`
4: `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

When I try to scaffold the database using the following command in the package manager console

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=SampleDB" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir SampleEFMySQL -f
```

I get the following Error.

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

How do I work with MySQL using Entity Framwork Core(in .net core 2.0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Connector/NET: [bug 89310](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89310), also reported as [bug 90368](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90368).

Many people (e.g., [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10702#issuecomment-358380406) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41659935)) recommend switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) instead (to use MySQL with Entity Framework Core on .NET Core).