# .NET Core EntityFramework Doesn't Create Scaffolding for Existing MySql Database

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

Trying to create scaffolding for an already existing MySql database using the instructions at [Scaffolding an Existing Database in EF Core](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html)

Using EF Core 2.0 and MySQL.DataEntityFrameworkCore{Design} 6.10.6.  When I run the following (redacted) command in the in the Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=111.2.33.44;port=3306;user=xxx;password=yyy;database=zzz" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore  -OutputDir DB -f
```

which should get me the scaffolding files in DB which is a C# class library.

Instead I get the error:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ModelScaffolder.Generate(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas, String projectPath, String outputPath, String rootNamespace, String contextName, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

The thing is, I'm not trying to create a database, only implement an interface to an already existing database.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I was able to get the scaffolding by installing Pomelo and running "Scaffold-DbContext "server=111.2.33.44;port=3306;user=xxx;password=yyy;database=zzz" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql  -OutputDir DB -f"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The method or operation is not implemented. while scaffolding MYSQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616506/error-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-while-scaffolding-mysql-datab)

Answer (score 4):

The package `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` doesn't support scaffolding at the moment I am posting and raises `NotImplementedException`.

To scaffold the entities from MySQL database you could use the alternative package [`Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) (read *Getting Started* section about manually adding `DotNetCliToolReference` to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`).

With `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` the command for `Package Manager Console` will look like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "your-mysql-connection-string" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir DB -f
```

Comment: Right @KevinJohnsrude, just want to make this question answered and provide some more details on how to make this working.