# Having troubles with TINYINT or BIT types mapping using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore package

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I using DB first approach and I trying to create EF models based on existing DB.
I trying to represent boolean type from my column.

First I tried to set is as `TINYINT(1)` type, then I generating EF model and I see `byte` type for this column. 
I tried many approaches to set it to 0 without success. 
I tried simple assignment `=0` to this variable, then I tried to use `Convert.ToByte(false)` method both of them were without success.

My next step was changing `TINYINT(1)` to `BIT(1)` type. Then EF generated `short` type for my column. I can't assign 0 value via this `short` type as well.

What is my mistake?

Comment: You can use this mapping configuration for your Pomelo provider..
https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/datatypemapping.html

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're encountering MySQL [bug 92987](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92987). (See also [bug 93028](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93028) which is similar.)

Since Oracle hasn't even confirmed those issues, let alone indicated any priority for fixing them, you may want to try switching to [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), an alternate MySQL EF.Core implementation; many people have reported that it's a lot more reliable (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656553/skip-and-take-not-working-with-mysql-entityframeworkcore/41659935#41659935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46089982/ef-core-update-database-on-mysql-fails-with-efmigrationshistory-doesnt-ex/46090571#46090571)).

Comment: 93028 comment from Bradley Grainger helped me. I changed my database type to tinyint(1) from the generated tinyint(4). If you have access to that. He says they need to be nullable but that part didn't affect my mapping. Not sure if there is other code within the Connector/NET that will error if it's not nullable though, so it's probably best to go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed the default value to NULL in MySQL and then EF generated nullable `short?` type for me.
Strange things, but this time mapping works correctly.